# Weird issue with related entity in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'm using Doctrine2 inside Symfony and I have the following setup:

An Item class:

```
/**
 * Class Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OneShortly\CommonBundle\Entity\ItemRepository")
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="primaryCategory", referencedColumnName="foreignId")
     */
    private $primaryCategory;
}
```

And a Category class:

```
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OneShortly\CommonBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="foreignId", type="integer", unique=true)
     */
    private $foreignId;
}
```

Now when I do this:

```
$item = new Item();
$item->setPrimaryCategory($category);
$this->em->persist($item);
$this->em->flush();
```

I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]   Notice:
>   Undefined index: foreignId in
>   home/www/project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 692

Now, I've been looking at this from all angles and still cannot see what is wrong with this code. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more digging I figured out myself by using *doctrine:schema:validate*:

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class
>   'Acme\CommonBundle\Entity\Item' mapping is invalid:
>   * The referenced column name 'foreignId' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class
>   'Acme\CommonBundle\Entity\Category'.
>
> [Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current
>   mapping file.

So, I changed the foreign key from foreignId to id (which happens to be the primary key) and it works. I could, of course, just use foreignId as a primary key, but I realized actually I don't need that.

Comment: This caught me out... I thought I could link to any unique field on the related entity, but it has to be the PK

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata.

You should rather have:

```
/**
 * Class Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OneShortly\CommonBundle\Entity\ItemRepository")
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $primaryCategory;
}
```

and:

```
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OneShortly\CommonBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 */
 class Category
 {
     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="primaryCategory")
      */
      private $items;
 }
```

Forget ID in ORM.